# Dreamweaver CS5: Spry Fading Flickering

Tags: javascript, adobe, dreamweaver, flash-cs5, spry

I've been using Dreamweaver CS5's Spry framework to build my website, and have had some issues with fading.

I have the following code:

```
<area shape="poly" coords="113,12,8,14,3,84,7,150,6,168,105,168,105,196,167,198,179,198,192,197,248,198,248,169,364,166,361,96,193,96,192,68,155,68,133,68,114,68" onmouseover="MM_effectAppearFade('BannerGlow', 250, 0, 100, false)" onmouseout="MM_effectAppearFade('BannerGlow', 250, 100, 0, false)" />
```

Which makes the sites banner glow by fading in a glowing version of the image behind it upon mousing over the area.

The problem here is that it takes 250ms for the glow to fade in smoothly, and if you move your mouse out of the area in those 250ms, it will activate the fadeout effect with the fadein effect still running, resulting in obnoxious flickering.

Anyone know any way around this?